# Python returning 0's instead of value

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I'm working on a project where I need to convert SAS code to Python. I've gotten most of the script converted but I'm having an issue with the following SAS snippet:

```
if balloondt_i <= intnx('month',datadt,1,'end') then prinamt = currbal;
else do;
    do i = 1 to dpd_mult;
        if currbal > 0 then do;
            intbal = currbal * rate / 1200 * pmtfreq;
            if      int_only = 'IO'  then prinbal = 0;
            else if intbal >= pmtamt then prinbal = mort(currbal,.,rate*pmtfreq/1200,max(1,(intck('month',datadt,balloondt)-((i-1)*pmtfreq)))/pmtfreq) - intbal;
            else                          prinbal = pmtamt - intbal;

            currbal = currbal - prinbal;
            prinamt = prinamt + prinbal;
            intamt  = intamt + intbal;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I've created a sample data set below for Python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'loannum': [111, 222],
    'datadt': [dt.datetime(2023, 12, 31), dt.datetime(2023, 12, 31)],
    'balloondt_i': [dt.datetime(2026, 6, 1), dt.datetime(2031, 3, 1)],
    'balloondt': [dt.datetime(2026, 6, 1), dt.datetime(2031, 3, 1)],
    'currbal': [2171044.89, 2020983.87],
    'rate': [5.50, 4.17],
    'pmtfreq': [1, 1],
    'int_only': [None, None],
    'dpd_mult': [1, 3],
    'prinbal': [0, 0],
    'prinamt': [0, 0],
    'pmtamt': [77622.93, 26188.26],
    'intamt': [0, 0],
    'intbal': [0, 0]
})
```

The Python code I've come up with to replicate the SAS snippet is below:

```
for idx in df.index:
    datadt = df.loc[idx, 'datadt']
    balloondt_i = df.loc[idx, 'balloondt']
    currbal = df.loc[idx, 'currbal']
    rate = df.loc[idx, 'rate']
    pmtfreq = df.loc[idx, 'pmtfreq']
    pmtamt = df.loc[idx, 'pmtamt'] if not pd.isna(df.loc[idx, 'pmtamt']) else None
    int_only = df.loc[idx, 'int_only']

    if balloondt_i <= datadt + relativedelta(months=+1):  # Approximates 'intnx'
        df.loc[idx, 'prinamt'] = df.loc[idx, 'currbal']
    else:
        for i in range(df.loc[idx, 'dpd_mult']):
            if currbal <= 0:  # Break if current balance is zero or negative
                break
            intbal = df.loc[idx, 'currbal'] * rate / 1200 * pmtfreq
            if int_only == 'IO':
                prinbal = 0
            elif intbal >= pmtamt:
                nperiods = max(1, (balloondt_i.year - datadt.year) * 12 + (balloondt_i.month - datadt.month) - (i - 1) * pmtfreq)
                prinbal = npf.pmt(rate * pmtfreq / 1200 / 12, nperiods, df.loc[idx, 'currbal']) - intbal  # Use np.pmt()
            else:
                prinbal = pmtamt - intbal
                df.loc[idx, 'currbal'] -= prinbal
                df.loc[idx, 'prinamt'] += prinbal
                df.loc[idx, 'intamt'] += intbal
```

The Python code calculates most of the attributes correctly. However, `prinbal` and `intbal` are returned with `0`. I've tried moving the calculation for `intbal` inside the first `if` statement before the `break` but that yielded the same results. My desired output is below:

| loannum | datadt | balloondt_i | balloondt | currbal | rate | pmtfreq | int_only | dpd_mult | prinbal | prinamt | pmtamt | intamt | intbal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2023-12-31 | 2026-06-01 | 2026-06-01 | 2171044.89 | 5.50 | 1 | None | 1 | 67672.307588 | 67672.307588 | 77622.93 | 9950.622413 | 9950.622413 |
| 222 | 2023-12-31 | 2031-03-01 | 2031-03-01 | 2020983.87 | 4.17 | 1 | None | 3 | 19298.771606 | 57696.053269 | 26188.26 | 20868.726731 | 6889.488395 |

Comment: A couple of observations, `range` in python is indexed starting at zero, so `i` is not going to have the same value as the SAS code. `prinbal` and `intbal` are being updated as python variables but not updated in the `df` (whereas doing `df.loc[idx, 'currbal'] = ` will update the df - I think). Finally, use `print()` in your Python code to debug, e.g. `print(intbal)`

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation issue in your code, which makes the calculation of `prinbal` and `intbal` to be outside of the loop where `currbal` is being updated.

Your code should be

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy_financial as npf

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'loannum': [111, 222],
    'datadt': [dt.datetime(2023, 12, 31), dt.datetime(2023, 12, 31)],
    'balloondt_i': [dt.datetime(2026, 6, 1), dt.datetime(2031, 3, 1)],
    'balloondt': [dt.datetime(2026, 6, 1), dt.datetime(2031, 3, 1)],
    'currbal': [2171044.89, 2020983.87],
    'rate': [5.50, 4.17],
    'pmtfreq': [1, 1],
    'int_only': [None, None],
    'dpd_mult': [1, 3],
    'prinbal': [0, 0],
    'prinamt': [0, 0],
    'pmtamt': [77622.93, 26188.26],
    'intamt': [0, 0],
    'intbal': [0, 0]
})

for idx in df.index:
    datadt = df.loc[idx, 'datadt']
    balloondt_i = df.loc[idx, 'balloondt_i']
    currbal = df.loc[idx, 'currbal']
    rate = df.loc[idx, 'rate']
    pmtfreq = df.loc[idx, 'pmtfreq']
    pmtamt = df.loc[idx, 'pmtamt'] if not pd.isna(df.loc[idx, 'pmtamt']) else None
    int_only = df.loc[idx, 'int_only']

    if balloondt_i <= datadt + relativedelta(months=+1):  
        df.loc[idx, 'prinamt'] = df.loc[idx, 'currbal']
    else:
        for i in range(df.loc[idx, 'dpd_mult']):
            if currbal <= 0:  
                break
            intbal = df.loc[idx, 'currbal'] * rate / 1200 * pmtfreq
            if int_only == 'IO':
                prinbal = 0
            else:
                if intbal >= pmtamt * pmtfreq:
                    nperiods = max(1, (balloondt_i.year - datadt.year) * 12 + (balloondt_i.month - datadt.month) - (i - 1) * pmtfreq)
                    prinbal = npf.pmt(rate * pmtfreq / 1200 / 12, nperiods, df.loc[idx, 'currbal']) - intbal  
                else:
                    prinbal = pmtamt * pmtfreq - intbal
            df.loc[idx, 'currbal'] -= prinbal
            df.loc[idx, 'prinamt'] += prinbal
            df.loc[idx, 'intamt'] += intbal

print(df)
```

Which gives

```
   loannum     datadt balloondt_i  balloondt       currbal  rate  pmtfreq  \
0      111 2023-12-31  2026-06-01 2026-06-01  2.103373e+06  5.50        1   
1      222 2023-12-31  2031-03-01 2031-03-01  1.963288e+06  4.17        1   

  int_only  dpd_mult  prinbal       prinamt    pmtamt        intamt  intbal  
0     None         1        0  67672.307587  77622.93   9950.622413       0  
1     None         3        0  57696.053269  26188.26  20868.726731       0
```